# Objects appearing in front of each other and unable to click on vertices in X-Ray mode after 3.6

Tags: 3d-view

Trying to select objects in *Edit Mode* and faces on other parts of the meshes somehow "appear" in front of others with these sort of "shadows" that show up, especially if there's a lot of faces near each other as well as being unable to snap to objects in edit mode with *X-Ray* on.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.